# Additional information on first occurrence of a product name

Tags: cross-referencing

I refer to companies and products multiple times throughout my publication. The first time I mention a product I would like to provide additional information about this product like so:

```
Microsoft Kinect (Micosoft Inc., Redmond, WA, USA).
```

What I'm looking for is a way to define those similar to `\newacronym` and `\gls` so that the first (and only the first) occurrence of a product always contains the additional information. Is there a package I can use that achieves this?

Comment: Why don't you use an acronym then?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Can I define an acronym that does not show up in the glossary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned `\gls`, here's how to do it with `glossaries`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{mk}{name={Microsoft Kinect},
 first={Microsoft Kinect (Microsoft Inc., Redmond, WA, USA)},
 text={Microsoft Kinect},
 description={}
 }

\begin{document}

First: \gls{mk}.

Next: \gls{mk}.
\end{document}
```

[image: image of result]

If you want a glossary but don't want this entry included, you can create an "ignored glossary" and use the `type` key:

```
\documentclass{article}    

\usepackage{glossaries} 

\makeglossaries

\newignoredglossary{ignore}

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\newglossaryentry{mk}{name={Microsoft Kinect},
 first={Microsoft Kinect (Microsoft Inc., Redmond, WA, USA)},
 text={Microsoft Kinect},
 description={},
 type=ignore
 }

\begin{document} 

First: \gls{mk}.

Next: \gls{mk}.

\gls{sample}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: image of resulting document]

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is going to show up in the glossary isn't it? Can I prevent that in some way?

Comment: @Androidicus I've updated my answer.